# Floating action button displays png differently?

Tags: android, floating-action-button

Floating Action Button shows a png different than what it is.

Here is the same image used in an ImageView with background set as null
[image: png in an ImageView]

Here is the same png image but used in a FloatingActionButton
[image: same png in a FloatingActionButton]

This is weird, can someone explain why is this happening ? And how to fix it ?

UPDATE: Here are the layout files for the same

ImageButton

```
...............
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/submit_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/mobile_number_submit_button"
            android:background="@null"/>
......................
```

FloatingActionButton

```
.......................
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/otp_submit_floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/submit_button" />
.......................
```

Comment: Can you show the xml of how do you go about doing it?

Comment: can you share the layout file code here ?

Comment: Added the layout code in the question... submit_button and mobile_number_submit_button are copies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is not a good idea to put an image with a colored circle inside an floating action button because it is already a colored circle button so you need to put an image icon with only the icon with transparent background (in your case an arrow ">" without the colored circle that is provided by the floating action button itself)

Comment: but icon is still very small

Answer (score 1):

FloatingActionButton set the accent color by default. So you need to make the icon transparent and everything will be fine .

Comment: The icon's background is indeed already set as transparent.... I used photoshop to create the image (Just adding if it helps).

Comment: i mean , remove the red color. only keep the white (Arrow sign) icon.

Comment: but icon is still very small